# What is 'Vasyan Upload Complete' in Cyberpunk 2077

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I got a statusbar with the title 'Vasyan Upload Complete' at 89% displayed in my HUD. What does it mean, how to get rid off it? I'm lost.

Comment: If this is stuck on your screen, it's probably a bug. Saving your game and reload it should clear it. This is one of the messages that can appear when you're being remotely hacked.

Comment: thanks, save and reload did not solve it but the 1.04 patch got rid of it.

Comment: This should be closed as no-repro now, but not sure if that is an option on Arqade or if I just can't see it since I'm below 3k reputation at the moment.

Comment: Don't see an option for no repro on close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue seems to be fixed with Patch 1.04